# Go to page and open link there, in one go

Tags: javascript, html, web

I’m guessing if this is possible at all, it has to be done via javascript, although I’d prefer a solution that doesn’t use it, if possible.

I have an html page (let’s call it **TWO**) that uses [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to display an iframe after clicking on a link.

I also have another page (**ONE**) that has a link that when clicked, I want it to do the following

1. Go to page **TWO**.
2. Click on the link I want, to open said iframe.

This action from the link on page **ONE** will be repeated a lot, so the simpler the code, the better.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to do this

1. On Page Two read the refer using `document.referer` check to see if `document.referer=="one"`. This will ensure than the page is coming after clicking on one.html
2. If the document.referer equals one, use javascript or jquery to trigger click event on the colorbox link.

Since you havent shared how you are opening the colorbox the code for that may differ. But this can be achieved using above two steps code.

Comment: I don’t have experience with javascript, so I need some more details on how to exactly set this up. In this particular case, however, this solution would not work, since we can get from page **ONE** to **TWO** via another link, and that should not trigger the event.

Comment: You may need to read than around javascript without which you will not be able to work finer details. May be share what you have done so far and we both can fill in the blanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to give the anchor tag some class or id, and in this way use the referrer as “if you got to this page following a link with class x, (…)”?

Comment: It can be possible to find a way but i would suggest you to just do a alert(document.referer) on the page two first, then you can append #tags to different links on page 1, First try this please.

Comment: I’ve successfully tried that, I think I didn’t explain myself correctly on the previous comment. Since there’s more than one way of going from **ONE** to **TWO**, and I want this to happen only with one of those ways, is it possible for `referrer` to get the class/id/other of the link in question, so as to only act if it came from that specific link, and not the page?

Comment: Yes Seperate links like two.html#link1      two.html#link2 and then read the hash tag.

Comment: After some further reading, I’ve got it to work. Thank you for pointing me on the right direction. Accepted.